# Parsing json file with gson

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a problem creating a mapping for a json that i want to parse using json. It's very specific, its about a json file with a json array with objects in it.

my jsonfile starts like this:

```
  [
    {
        "venue": {
            "venue_seasons": [
                {
                    "created_at": "2011-12-25T23:00:28Z",
                    "updated_at": "2011-12-28T15:13:53Z",
                    "start_timestamp": 1293840000,
                    "id": 337,
                    "end": "2011-12-24T00:00:00Z",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "start": "2011-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                    "season_openings": [ … ],
                    "end_timestamp": 1324684800
                },
                { … }
            ],
            "address": "someadress",
            "city": "cityname",
            "name": "name",
            "created_at": "2011-03-31T07:55:33Z",
        etcetera
    }
    "venue":{another venue
```

So first an array, than an object (venue) with a lot of objects in it (i removed most of them, because thats not important for my question), and some arrays (like season_openings).

My parsing code works like this, im using gson. The inputstream works fine.

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
JsonResponse venueResponse = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonResponse.class);               
List<Venues> results = venueResponse.venue;
```

with the class JsonResponse:

```
public class JsonResponse {
    public List<Venues> venue;  
}
```

and Venues.class:

```
public class Venues {

    public List<VenueSeasons> venue_seasons;

    @SerializedName("adress")
    public String getAdress;

    @SerializedName("city")
    public String getCity;

    @SerializedName("country")
    public String getCountry; etcetera 
}
```

But when i run this code i get an error:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hera.android.JSON/com.hera.android.JSON.TestParser2Activity}: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2
```

Ofcourse i can read the error: it expects an objects but get an array. I varied a lot with different jsonresponse.class and even with putting the whole json array in a json object (what is not really a solution because i need to work with this type of jsonfile). But everytime i get this or a similar error.

I think I'm close to a solution, can anyone see what i just can't and give me a helping hand?
Thanks.

Comment: With the invalid example JSON and the incomplete invalid example Java code, folks that might try to help are left guessing about what's really going on.  It's a good practice to post complete minimal examples that demonstrate the problem trying to be resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling Gson like this:

```
List<Venues> venues = gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<Venues>>() {}.getType());
```

This works because your JSON document is a `List`, not an object that has a list as one of its properties.

Comment: i tried:  String name = venues.get(12).getName;
        Log.i(venuetag,"name of venue 12 is: " + name); but it gives for name a null value. Am i doing this right? I used venues.size() and it returned 471, so im sure my list works....

Comment: @Jasper, I'd guess that the Java data structure being deserialized to doesn't well enough match the JSON structure, and Gson is thus not binding the JSON "name" element to the Java "name" field.

Comment: @ProgrammerBruce At first, thank you for helping me. I checked the whole model yesterday, and removed some mistakes (used string instead of date) and checked everything for typo's, but still my data won't bind. My whole datastructure is a little more complicated, with some other arrays. Is there anything else I might do wrong? I think I'll build my model like in your post below, but don't really feel like building my entire model again... Now its comparable to the above, because i saw that in this post: [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

Comment: @Jasper "Is there anything else I might do wrong?" -- Nothing comes to mind.  As I mentioned in the other post, the key is to have matching data structures.